# Delete record from local storage using Akavache

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, akavache

I have a record that I store locally on the device and I have a button that deletes the record from local storage. When the user presses the button, this method is called and the record is removed from device locally (by invalidating the guid). I'm using Akavache to persist the data.

While this ends up working for the most part, I am noticing that sometimes when I delete the record and refresh the view, the record is deleted from the collection. However, if log out and log back into the app, the record reappears.

I'm wondering if this is the right approach to storing and deleting the record locally or not?

```
public async Task RemoveFormFromDevice(FormData form)
{
    string cacheKey = "data." + form.Guid.ToString ();

    await _cache.Invalidate (cacheKey);
    await _localStorage.Invalidate (cacheKey);

    List<KeyValuePair<Guid, int?>> guids = await _cache.Get<List<KeyValuePair<Guid, int?>>>(CACHE_KEY_PROCS);

    if (guids == null)
        return;

    guids.RemoveAll (a => a.Key == form.Guid);

    await _cache.Insert (CACHE_KEY_PROC, guids, null);
    await _localStorage.Insert (CACHE_KEY_PROCS, guids, null);
}
```

EDIT: Here's how I'm retrieving the records when I sign into the app:

```
private async Task<List<FormData>> getSavedProcs()
{
    List<FormData> forms = new List<FormData> ();

    List<KeyValuePair<Guid, int?>> guids = await _cache.Get<List<KeyValuePair<Guid, int?>>> (CACHE_KEY_PROCS);

    if (guids != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, int?> pair in guids)
        {
            string cacheKey = "data." + pair.Key.ToString ();
            string formJson = await _cache.Get<string> (cacheKey);

            FormData form = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormData> (formJson);
            if (form != null)
                forms.Add (form);
        }
    }
    return forms;
}

public async Task<T> Get<T>(string key) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        return await memoryCache.GetObject<T> (key);
    }
    catch(KeyNotFoundException ex) {
        T localStoreObj = await localStorage.Get<T> (key);

        if (localStoreObj != null)
            await this.Insert (key, localStoreObj);
        return localStoreObj;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return await Task.FromResult<T> (null);
    }
}

public virtual async Task<T> Get<T>(string key) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        return await encryptedCache.GetObject<T> (key);
    }
    catch(KeyNotFoundException ex) {
        return await Task.FromResult<T> (null);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return await Task.FromResult<T> (null);
    }
}


public async Task Insert<T>(string key, T value, DateTimeOffset? expiration = default(DateTimeOffset?)) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        await memoryCache.InsertObject<T> (key, value, expiration);
    }
    catch {
    }
}
```

Comment: could you attach the code how you store the record?

Comment: @ColeXia I updated my post. I'm showing the code that retrieves the forms when I sign back in and if the key is not found in the memorycache, it grabs it from local storage.

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Where do you get the record after you delete them, the memorycache or the local storage ? I suggest you  use SQL tool to judge whether the delete or get method  goes wrong

Comment: @ColeXia, What do you mean by SQL tool? It gets it from localStorage.

Comment: Akavache is based on SQLite3. OK , can you see the data in localStorage? Check the record whether  it still exists after you delete it. If yes, something wrong with the deleting method, if no ,then wrong with the getting method.